# Is our Beta label being removed?

Tags: discussion, beta

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293) and [Freelancing is graduating](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/25010) and [Retrocomputing is graduating](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/18437) and [Economics is graduating](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2161/20029), I'm curious if Medical Sciences will be too?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's no surprise to me that this Stack Exchange website was not chosen to graduated from beta, even though the requirements to do so are very low. This website has been falling into dereliction over the past several years.

Some ideas on why this website is failing:

- [What is the status of Medical Sciences (Dec '20)?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1260/43)
- [Change in my moderation practices](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1268/43)

[Carey Gregory](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/users/805/carey-gregory)'s [answer](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1313/43) is blaming COVID for causing the loss of a number of high-rep users in his answer, but the retention of experts has always been an issue, and I'd argue that COVID  should instead have helped revive this website due to the high interest of the public in the many COVID-related medical questions.

Even the two moderators themselves barely write any questions or answers on this website: over the past 2 years, the first one has posted ~20 answers and 0 questions, and the second one hasn't posted any answers or questions. The third moderator, who resigned a few weeks ago, hadn't posted any answers or questions for the past 5 years.

Comment: It's not the moderators' job to ask or answer questions. They're welcome to do so, of course, but like any other user.

Comment: Another nice hit piece, Frank. You know, moderator elections are coming in the next month or two, so this is your opportunity to fix all the problems you see here. I guarantee that if you run I will vote for you.

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks for offering to vote for me, unfortunately I'm already overcommitted with my research activities. I've contributed to over 5,000 answers and questions on Stack Exchange, so I feel I've already done a fair amount of volunteering work for this for-profit company. See [Why don’t you want to moderate?](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1458/6753) for some other reasons.

Comment: But you have apparently endless free time to explain what's wrong with this site and the people who moderate it. Yeah, got it, Frank.

Comment: @CareyGregory It's mostly to protect my questions and answers from removals that I perceive as unjustified (and as a side effect, it would help attract or keep other good contributors). Don't take it too personally, as in many cases the issue is Roomba deleting questions with a score of 0.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Likewise, don't take it too personally when your questions get ignored. I'm sure it's because this site and its moderators suck, not anything having to do with your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory  I don't mind when my questions are ignored. I do mind when they are removed.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Fine, then take it to meta.stackexchange and quit beating up on moderators here. We're not removing your questions.

Comment: @CareyGregory ->  [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. The moderators were informed of this earlier today by the Community Moderation team. The requirements for graduating from beta are 1) the site must have existed six months or more, 2) it must have at least 1000 open questions, and 3) at least 70% of the open questions must have at least one upvoted answer.

A site has to meet all 3 criteria but we failed on #3.

This site has always suffered from two major problems. The first is too many poor questions. We close a large number of questions every week, almost all of them due to lack of prior research or asking for personal medical advice. The second problem is too few people qualified to provide good answers. There are hundreds of good questions here with no answers, and that's why the site remains in beta. It's worth noting that we lost a number of high-rep users in 2020 because they were medical professionals and 2020 wasn't a good year for medical pros having a lot of free time on their hands.

Comment: There's worse problems with this site than the two you mentioned, but I'm not sure you want me to say them here.

Comment: @user1271772 This would be the place to say them. Feel free to speak up.

Comment: It's 6 minutes to midnight, I'll sleep over it and write a response later if I have time!